# customize the wsdl:binding name in jax ws implementation

Tags: java, web-services, soap, jax-ws

Is it possible to customize the wsdl:binding name in web services. I am using jax ws implementation.

```
@WebService(name="helloworldService",
portName="hellworldport",
serviceName = "helloworldService")
```

My binding is

```
<wsdl:binding name="helloworldServiceSoapBinding" type="tns:helloworldService">
```

I want to get it as

```
<wsdl:binding name="TestBinding" type="tns:helloworldService">
```

Can some one tell the required changes to be done.

Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4749175/define-binding-name-in-jax-ws