# get <xs:schema attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" > in wsdl

Tags: java, web-services, xsd

Currently my WSDLhas `<xs:schema attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="unqualified"`

I want o make it as `<xs:schema attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified"`

Can some one tell the way to achieve it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Example 2` in [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/xml/bind/annotation/XmlSchema.html) can help you. You have to specify the annotation something like:

```
xmlns = { @javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlNs(prefix = "po", 
               namespaceURI="http://www.example.com/myPO1") }
```

in @XmlSchema or wherever you provide the schema config.

**EDIT :**

Also, let me show you two examples of XML Schemas:

In the first case, XML namespace is prefixed with `wsdl`. This is an example of `qualified`.

```
<wsdl:definitions xmlns:wsdl='http://www.w3.org/2002/06/wsdl' >
  <wsdl:message />
</wsdl:definitions>
```

However, in this case, XML namespace is not prefixed. This is an example of `unqualified`.

```
<definitions xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2002/06/wsdl' >
  <message />
</definitions>
```

Comment: Thank you.Can you also tell the where should I use this annotation.

Comment: For that you have to post your code. I need the XmlSchema annotation code

Comment: Currently I have not written any code for XmlSchema. Its taken by default I guess

Comment: Which web service library are you using?

Comment: I got it. I used it in package-info.java. Thank you

Comment: So, did you use the same annotation as I suggested?

Comment: Can you help me on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14494161/customize-the-wsdlbinding-name-in-jax-ws-implementation